# GOOGLE FORMS: using regex to ALWAYS exclude certain words separated by commas

Tags: regex, forms, csv, expression, keyword

A Google Forms-specific REGEX question:

I am making a form in which users must input keywords, separated by commas. However, I want to make sure that certain words are flagged - no matter what order they appear in, whether the user has typed a comma or space after the forbidden word or not, and whether or not the user has put a word between two forbidden words (or not).

Here is what I'm using at the moment:

((badword|awfulword|horridword)\s?,?\s?)*

But when using the above, the forbidden words are NOT/NO LONGER flagged when users input the following:

CASE ONE:
(any forbidden word), okword

CASE TWO:
(forbidden word), (forbidden word), (forbidden word), okword

CASE THREE:
(any forbidden word), okword, (any forbidden word)

CASE FOUR
(any forbidden word), (partial word)

Any suggestions of how to edit the regex so that the forbidden words -- in any order and between any other word, words, or partial word -- will always flag in my Google Form?

Thanks!

Comment: If I test your regex with [Regex Tester](https://regex-golang.appspot.com/assets/html/index.html) and the text `CASE ONE: badword, okword
CASE TWO: awfulword, horridword, badword, okword
CASE THREE: awfulword, okword, horridword
CASE FOUR badword, awfulword`, all submatches of the forbidden words are found. You would have to provide a reproducible example to get help.